# cannot open source file "openssl/bn.h"

Tags: c++

```
#include <openssl/dh.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
```

Errors:cannot open source file "openssl/bn.h",cannot open source file "openssl/dh.h" ??? whats wrong

Comment: some more context would really help

Comment: So, do you actually have a file in the specified path by that name?

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure you have libssl installed on system. 
   If you are on linux use command

   $yum list libssl
2. If it is installed. Make sure you had given it's path in include directory. If you are using gcc you can tell gcc to search in directory by using

   -I /path_of_libssl folder

Answer (score 2):

You, probably, missing the include paths. If you are using Visual Studio, you should go to Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->C++ Directories and select from dropdown list option "include files" and add a path to openssl include folder. Either you can just copy openssl folder into your sources folder and change  to "openssl/bn.h".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that your compiler can not find the header file bn.h. The reason for this might be, that there is something wrong with your include path.

It might also be, that you did not install the header files. Depending on your system, you need to install a package which is called something like libssl-dev. This package contains the header files. The package libssl contains only the shared object files (ending with .so), these are needed for the linking process, not for the compiling process. If installing libssl-dev solves your problem and you run into a linker problem afterwards, you should also install libssl.