# Install pysqlcipher3 windows

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip, failed-installation, pysqlcipher

I need to install pysqlcipher on my windows computer but when I do:

```
pip install pysqlcipher
```

I have:

```
 Collecting pysqlcipher3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a4/06/1d56bdec3129eff6dd54323d249784ccd90ce03c8cae7870d45e434bae77/pysqlcipher3-1.0.3.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pysqlcipher3
  Building wheel for pysqlcipher3 (setup.py) ... done
  WARNING: Legacy build of wheel for 'pysqlcipher3' created no files.
  Command arguments: 'C:\Users\Elouan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Elouan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-827zddbs\\pysqlcipher3\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Elouan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-827zddbs\\pysqlcipher3\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Elouan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-jkj29o6_' --python-tag cp38
  Command output: [use --verbose to show]
  Running setup.py clean for pysqlcipher3
Failed to build pysqlcipher3
Installing collected packages: pysqlcipher3
  Running setup.py install for pysqlcipher3 ... done
Successfully installed pysqlcipher3
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I have tried to install it with git and I have:

```
python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
Builds a C extension linking against libsqlcipher library
building 'pysqlcipher3._sqlite3' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlcipher3.dbapi2\" -IC:\Users\Elouan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\Elouan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IF:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IF:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IF:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IF:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IF:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\python3\module.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\python3\module.obj
module.c
C:\Users\Elouan\pysqlcipher3\src\python3\connection.h(33): fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier include : 'sqlcipher/sqlite3.h' : No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I tried that with python3 but it's the same.
I think it's like this problem:
[Issue in installing pysqlcipher3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55446420/issue-in-installing-pysqlcipher3)
but I did not succeed to resolve the problem

Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 3):

### Install tlc (i'm use 8.6)

https://www.activestate.com/products/tcl/downloads/

(tclsh*.exe) is available in the PATH.(`tclsh C:\Tcl\bin\tclsh.exe`)

### Install VISUAL STUDIO (add) and VISUAL STUDIO C++ Build

go to microsoft

### Install OpenSSL x64 or x32 (i'm use x64)

https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

## add to PATH

### x64

```
OPENSSL_CONF C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg
```

### x32

```
OPENSSL_CONF C:\Program Files(x86)\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg
```

### in folder

`C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\lib`

### save copy

`libcrypto.def` and `libcrypto.lib`

### and rename at

`libeay32.def` and `libeay32.lib`

### save copy

`libssl.def` and `libssl.lib`

### and rename at

`ssleay32.def` and `ssleay32.lib`

### copy folder

`C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include\openssl`

### to

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include`

## Download sqlcipher

https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher

### in root sqlcipher change `Makefile.msc`

this

```
TCC = $(TCC) -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=1
```

change to

```
TCC = $(TCC) -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -I"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include"
```

next

```
# If ICU support is enabled, add the linker options for it.
#
!IF $(USE_ICU)!=0
LTLIBPATHS = $(LTLIBPATHS) /LIBPATH:$(ICULIBDIR)
LTLIBS = $(LTLIBS) $(LIBICU)
!ENDIF
# <</mark>>
# You should not have to change anything below this line
```

change to

```
# If ICU support is enabled, add the linker options for it.
#
!IF $(USE_ICU)!=0
LTLIBPATHS = $(LTLIBPATHS) /LIBPATH:$(ICULIBDIR)
LTLIBS = $(LTLIBS) $(LIBICU)
!ENDIF
# <</mark>>

LTLIBPATHS = $(LTLIBPATHS) /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\VC\static"
LTLIBS = $(LTLIBS) libcrypto64MT.lib libssl64MT.lib ws2_32.lib shell32.lib advapi32.lib gdi32.lib user32.lib crypt32.lib


# You should not have to change anything below this line
```

### x64 Native Tools Command (VS)

```
path\to\sqlcipher>

nmake /f Makefile.msc clean
nmake /f Makefile.msc
```

## Download `pysqlcipher3`

https://github.com/rigglemania/pysqlcipher3

### create folder

`/amalgamation` in `/pysqlcipher3`

### COPY TWO FILES FROM `/sqlcipher`

`sqlite3.c` `sqlite3.h`

### TO `/pysqlcipher3/amalgamation`

## Download `sqlite-amalgamation`

https://sqlite.org/download.html

i'm use https://sqlite.org/2021/sqlite-amalgamation-3340100.zip

### create folder

`/pysqlcipher3/src/python3/sqlcipher`

### copy 4 files from `sqlite-amalgamation-3340100.zip`

`shell.c sqlite3.c sqlite.h sqliteext.h`

### to

`/pysqlcipher3/src/python3/sqlcipher`

### x64 Native Tools Command (VS)

```
path\to\pysqlcipher3>

setup.py clean  
enter code here
setup.py build_amalgamation

setup.py install
```

Comment: I am following your steps precisely but run into errors on the last step `setup.py build_amalgamation`. It says"src\python3\cache.c(261): error C2017: illegal escape sequence" and "error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'Node'" and "error C2001: newline in constant" and "error C2224: left of '.Cache' must have struct/union type" and "error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2"

Comment: Having just gone through the process of compiling pysqlcipher, the fix is to replace all instances of MODULE_NAME with "pysqlcipher3.dbapi2" (quotes must be included) in the files in the source folder pysqlcipher3\src\python3. I used Textcrawler Free to replace them. I used the latest versions of sqlcipher, pysqlcipher and amalgamation files. It compiles fine in the current python 3.11.4 (June 2023) and older versions. Hope this helps anyone struggling to compile it.